# Get value of radio button using li class name

Tags: jquery, class

Here i want get the value of input type radio button and i want check the input type radio button is prop checked true or false using the li  `class="gchoice_38_1"`

so my question is the how can check the radio button is prop checked or not.

```
<li class="gchoice_38_1">
    <input type="radio" onclick="gf_apply_rules(29,[8,37,46]);" tabindex="4" id="choice_29_38_1" checked="checked" value="no" name="input_38">
    <label id="label_29_38_1" for="choice_29_38_1">no</label>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : iterate all radio buttons inside `li` having `class="gchoice_38_1"`, use `is(':checked')` to find the checked status

```
$('li.gchoice_38_1 input[type=radio]').each(function(){
   alert('Radio checked status : '+$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

pass this `onclick="gf_apply_rules(this,29,[8,37,46])`

```
function gf_apply_rules(elm,no,arr){

    alert(elm.checked);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fnxu07hv/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
$("input :radio[name=input_38]").click(function(){
 var val=$(this).val();
});
```